# Shell script assign variable value to another new variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need a small correction for my below code. I am trying to assign variable value to another variable, but it's not working. please help me.

Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
choice=1
VAL1="test"
if [ "$choice" == 1 ];
then
   echo "insode"
   echo $choice
   purpose=$VAl1
   echo "*"
   echo $purpose
fi
```

Please help me, I'm new to shell scripting. I need to display `purpose` value as test.

Comment: What is the actual output of the script, and what would you expect for output?

Comment: Dear sir, thanks for reply. just i am trying to assign VA1L1 varibale value to purpose variable in if. when i echo $porpose it should display test. but now its not diplaying test.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Look at your VAL1 variable. You incorrectly set purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You assign a value to `VAL1`:

```
VAL1="test"
```

But later you assign `$VAl1` to `purpose`:

```
purpose=$VAl1
```

You just have to fix the case so the variable names match (fix lowercase `l` to uppercase `L`).

Comment: Additionally, you should properly quote the value when you use it; `echo "$VAL1"`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable